# Sorting an array of NSURL objects by creation date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

My caches images to a directory (/Library/Caches/ImageCache/).  When the directory exceeds a certain size I would like to delete the oldest file in the directory.  To accomplish this task I use NSFileManager to retrieve the directory contents.  I then try to sort this array by date and delete the oldest object.

My problem is that my program crashes when I try to sort the array by the key NSURLCreationDateKey.

```
NSFileManager *defaultFM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, NSURLCreationDateKey, nil];
NSURL *cacheDirectory = [self photoCacheDirectory];  // method that returns cache URL
NSArray *cacheContents = [defaultFM contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:cacheDirectory
                                  includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                                     options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants
                                                       error:nil];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:NSURLCreationDateKey ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [cacheContents sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

The program crashes on the last line. With error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key NSURLCreationDateKey.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT : Better answer**

If that doesn't work, you will have to write your own comparator block and get the dates to compare manually :(

```
[cacheContents sortUsingComparator:^ (NSURL *a, NSURL *b) {
    // get the two dates
    id da = [[a resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLCreationDateKey] error:nil] objectForKey:NSURLCreationDateKey];
    id db = [[b resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLCreationDateKey] error:nil] objectForKey:NSURLCreationDateKey];

    // compare them
    return [da compare:db];
}];
```

(Same disclaimer still applies but I'm not even sure that will compile ;) - you get the idea though!)

---

**Here is my first answer (included here for posterity but mostly it just shows how important it is to read the question properly :)**

It's because you're getting an array of `NSURL` objects; these don't have a `NSURLCreationDateKey` property.

Try this (disclaimer - not 100% it will work)

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fileAttributes.%@", NSURLCreationDateKey];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key ascending:YES];
```

Your key to sort by is a property of the fileAttributes dictionary which is, in turn, a property of your enumerator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion dean.  I'm still getting the same error though.

Comment: If shouldn't be exactly the same, it should say `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fileAttributes.NSURLCreationDateKey.'` - anyway, see my edit for another solution :)

Comment: OK, I'm an idiot - I've been assuming you're using enumerators but looking at your question, you're obviously not. I'm an idiot! see my edited edit for a comparator block that should help do what you want!

Comment: Ron, thank you!  That worked.  I also came to a silly realization that since my program adds the files to the directory in order that they are viewed the ones at the beginning of the returned array, cacheContents, are always the newest!... I'm not sure if this is ALWAYS a safe thing to assume so the comparator is a better method.  Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: I'm always explicit; if I want to display something in an order, I sort it (unless the documentation specifically says it will be in that order!). you never know if it's just coincidence or if it will change in later versions of iOS etc :)

Comment: Btw, sorry I was saying Ron and I meant dean - not sure why I was doing that...

One last thing on the solution I believe it's NSURLCreationDateKey instead of NSURLCreateDateKey.

Comment: Ron's answer was spot on as well :) I've edited my answer to fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about this, but I think that the contentsOfDirectoryAtURL: method returns a list of URLs which are not KVC objects. To get the property you want from the NSURL, you need to call:

`getResourceValue:forKey:error:`

Since this is not KVC compatible, you won't be able to use a sort descriptor, and instead need to use a routine like [cacheContents sortedArrayUsingComparator:...]

Comment: Hi Ron, you are right. Contents returns an array of NSURL objects which I can individually access the keys for by doing:

    NSURL *url = [cachedContents objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *values = [url resourceValuesForKeys:keys error:nil];

Using a comparator would I have to implement another method in my class to compare the two dates given by the NSURL objects?